# Restkit and google analitycs

Tags: google-analytics, restkit, spring-3

I have developed an APP that uses restkit and connect to my server. The server side was built using spring 3.1 and jackson to generate the rest objects.

Now I want to mesuare the APP trafic but I cant find a way for google analitycs track the rest querys.

is this posible?? any recomendation??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For Google Analytics you should add the [Google Analytics iOS library](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/) to your application and perhaps tie Events to the different REST calls your app makes.

Otherwise you'd have to generate statistics yourself from your web server logs based on the requests coming from iOS User-agents.